# How to make speech recognition continous for a fix time period?

Tags: javascript, jquery, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, webspeech-api

I want to make my speech recognition JavaScript to record continuously for a Fixed time period let's say 5 min.

my js has the following code

```
try {
  var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
}
catch(e) {
  // console.error(e);
  $('.no-browser-support').show();
  //$('.app').hide();
}

var noteTextarea = $('#note-textarea');
var instructions = $('#recording-instructions');
var notesList = $('ul#notes');

var noteContent = '';

// Get all notes from previous sessions and display them.
var notes = getAllNotes();
renderNotes(notes);


$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
   if (noteContent.length) {
      noteContent += ' ';
   }

   recognition.start();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onend` property of the `SpeechRecognition` interface represents an event handler that will run when the speech recognition service has disconnected (when the end event fires). So you can start `SpeechRecognition` again when this event occurs with `start()`

So, finally you should have something like

```
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
 ...

recognition.onend = function() {
  recognition.start();
}
```

To make it go for five minutes, you can use timer etc. like `setInterval` and add a check in `onend` callaback to check to start `recognition` again or not. Something like

```
var counter = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
      counter++;
},1000)


recognition.onend = function() {
 if(counter <= 5 * 60)
  recognition.start();
 else
   clearInterval(interval)
}
```

And please not that `recognition` stops exactly after 5 minutes but for minimum 5 minutes

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/onend)

Comment: I want to do it for 5 mins only. then what will be the code for doing this?

Comment: i am using this code but i am getting error Speech already started  in end function @Bailey

Comment: and what if user stops after 2 min what will happen ?